# Can I use <link> tags in the body of an HTML document?

Tags: seo, html, html5, microdata

Can I use `<link>` tags in the body of an HTML page? I tried to find the answer to this question, but found contradictory information.

When adding Schema.org microdata markup to an HTML page, I want to add canonical info in a link tag like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <span itemprop="name">The Catcher in the Rye</span>—
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catcher_in_the_Rye" />
  by <span itemprop="author">J.D. Salinger</span>
</div>
```

I got the example code above from [Schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html). According to them, this is the way to go for people that want to add a canonical reference to an itemprop, but don't want to place a hyperlink on their website.

W3 however clearly states that `<link>` tags should only be placed within the head section, thus making the Schema.org example invalid.

If I want to stick to correct markup, which advice should I follow?

Comment: You are linking to *w3schools.com* (which has nothing to do with the W3C), not *w3.org*.

Comment: Ah, yes of course, you're right. Removed the link to W3schools. Thanks.

Comment: Here is what happens to SEO: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Microdata** [extends](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#content-models) HTML5 in a way that `link` and `meta` elements can be used in the `body`, **if** they contain an `itemprop` attribute.

> If the `itemprop` attribute is present on `link` or `meta`, they are flow content and phrasing content. The `link` and `meta` elements may be used where phrasing content is expected if the `itemprop` attribute is present.

This extension is currently also included in the HTML 5.1 Nightly (Editor’s Draft)  (see [`link` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) and [`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element)). But as the [Microdata specification became a W3C Note](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/) recently, we’ll have to see what happens with this reference.

**RDFa 1.1** [extends](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax) HTML5 in a way that `link` and `meta` elements can be used in the `body`, if they contain a `propertỳ` attribute.

> If the `@property` RDFa attribute is present on the `link` or `meta` elements, they MUST be viewed as conforming if used in the `body` of the document. More specifically, when `link` or `meta` elements contain the RDFa `@property` attribute and are used in the `body` of an HTML5 document, they MUST be considered flow content.

---

So you are **not** allowed to use *any* `link` element in the `body`, but only those

- with an `itemprop` attribute (for Microdata), or
- with a `property` attribute (for RDFa), or
- with a `rel` value that is defined as "body-ok" (see [zgreen’s answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/137977/17633)).

Thus your `link` element can be used in the `body`:

```
<body>
<!-- … -->
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catcher_in_the_Rye" />
<!-- … -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand correctly, I'm allowed to use the `<link>` tag in the body as long as it contains an itemprop attribute? And as long as the itemprop attribute is included, I can also include `href` as used in my original question?

Comment: @EdwardTouw: Yes; you MUST give the `href` attribute in any case. So as long as the `link` element has an `itemprop` attribute, you may use it in the `body`. Then it no longer is metadata for the whole document (like it would be the case for usual `link` elements in the `head`), but a "hidden" element for Microdata.

Comment: This answer is wrong. [zgreens' answer below](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/137977/81312) is correct and includes relevant quotes and links to MDN and the W3C spec.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert: In case you are not aware, at the time of OP’s question (2013), "body-ok" didn’t exist yet, so my answer was accurate back then. Also note that zgreen’s answer is not complete, as it misses the case with the `property` attribute which I described in my answer.  –– Thanks for the notice. I’ll edit my answer to include the additonal cases.

Answer (score 12):

W3Schools does not set the industry standards on HTML coding. They are simply a 3rd party  reference site that is [not affiliated with the W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) in anyway. W3Schools and other sites are often wrong when using cutting edge coding technologies such as [Schema](http://schema.org/) and [Responsive design](http://www.w3.org/2013/Talks/responsive-design.pdf). When using fairly new code your one stop shop should be [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) as set the compliance standards, and maybe [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) if you need help understanding HTML5 through they are not official but highly respected.

Looking at your code it passes [W3C validation](http://validator.w3.org) without any issues with the link element contained within the `<body> </body>`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <span itemprop="name">The Catcher in the Rye</span>—
  <link itemprop="url" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catcher_in_the_Rye" />
  by <span itemprop="author">J.D. Salinger</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***SHORT ANSWER:*** Yes, you can use `<LINK>` within `<body> </body>` but as Unor has mentioned in his answer must include itemprop.

Comment: Note that you are linking to a HTML5 draft from 2009. In the [current HTML5 CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) the relevant definition is not included.

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked and answered some time ago, and things have improved a quite a bit since then. You **can** use `<link>` tags in the `<body>` of an HTML document as long as the `<link>` has a type that is "body-ok".

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link):

> A  element can occur either in the `<head>` or `<body>` element, depending on whether it has a link type that is body-ok. For example, the stylesheet link type is body-ok, and therefore `<link rel="stylesheet">` is permitted in the body. However, this isn't a good practice to follow; it makes more sense to separate your  elements from your body content, putting them in the `<head>`.

[According to html.spec.whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#allowed-in-the-body):

> If a `link` element has an `itemprop` attribute, or has a `rel` attribute that contains only keywords that are body-ok, then the element is said to be allowed in the body. This means that the element can be used where phrasing content is expected.

[body-ok keywords are as follows](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok):

- `dns-prefetch`
- `modulepreload`
- `pingback`
- `preconnect`
- `prefetch`
- `preload`
- `prerender`
- `stylesheet`

Relevant links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#body-ok
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#allowed-in-the-body
- https://jakearchibald.com/2016/link-in-body/

Answer (score 0):

The link element can be added to the body of an HTML document if the `itemprop` attribute is present. Here's a [demo](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/link/html5_link_tag_nested.php).

Also here's a [link itemprop](http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/html5_attributes/link/html5_link_itemprop_attribute.php) attribute example.

Comment: If these are links to your site, please add a disclaimer like "I covered this in my blog here...".