# Breadcrumbs with <div>, <span> or <li>?

Tags: html5, microdata, breadcrumbs

Does it matter whether my microdata breadcrumb trail starts and ends with `<div>`, `<span>` or `<li>`? Consider `<div>` tag first:

```
<div><span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <a href="http://www.example.com/dresses" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">Dresses</span>
  </a></span> » 
</div>
```

And now what if I replace it with `<li>` or `<span>` tags? What difference it would make?

I saw this `<li>` in website's breadcrumbs and it displayed without showing bullet points.

UPDATE: Look what I just found:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
<a href="http://www.example.com/" itemprop="url">
<span itemprop="title">Dresses</span>
</a>
</span> >> 
<span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
<span a href="http://www.example.com/" itemprop="url"></span>
<span itemprop="title">Last Page**</span>
</a>
</span>
```

Normally last page is not displayed in search results unless it has URL propery. However I was able to make it display in a non-hyperlinked way in green. How is that looked upon by Google?

Comment: Shame you didn't mention `<nav>` with `<ul>` because that's more relevant than all of the ones mentioned ;) I recommend you research about span, p, a, div, section, main, nav, ul and so on.

Comment: Is it same as SPAN and DIV when it comes to breadcrumbs or it boosts your rankings too? ;)

Comment: Span, DIV has nothing to do with rankings... Also microdata does not directly improve rankings.

Comment: That's a whole different question, and since you're using breadcrumbs, what is the point of having that without the url property?

Comment: @guisasso Seems there is no point of having trail without URL but I just discovered how you can still have it without URL.

Comment: @Boris_yo It's because the link is set incorrectly within the span tag

Answer (score 3):

If the code is validated, no.

The following is:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/" itemprop="url">
         <span itemprop="title">Dresses</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Gets validated with any of those tags (`<span>`, `<li>`, `<div>`) and many more.

Try it out at http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets.

P.S.: Your first `<div>` tag is closed on your example, which makes it not functional.

Answer (score 1):

For the Microdata, it does not matter if you use `div`, `span` or `li`.

Using this is invalid, of course (`span` can’t have the attributes `a` and `href`):

```html
<span a href="http://www.example.com/" itemprop="url"></span>
```

If you want to provide a URL without having a clickable/visible link, use the `link` element (which [can be used in the `body`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633) if used for Microdata):

```html
<link itemprop="url" href="http://www.example.com/" />
```